# MongoDB shard by date on a single machine

Tags: mongodb, sharding

We have started with one single mongodb but no we have one collection grown to ~300GB. The collection contains objects which have a date field. But mostly we just need to query the more recent objects then the historic once. So my question is: is it possible to shard this collection on one server by a date field? More explicitly I would like to shard more recent objects into one node and older objects into another node. Instead of equally distributing all the objects on n shards.

And is there a tutorial how one can shard an existing single database (without any replica sets) into a sharded cluster?

Comment: ... implying that at some point, "old" data would migrate from one server to the other ?

Comment: Why would you want to shard? You'd still need an index over said date field in case you need to access older values **and** you'd reduce the amount of usable RAM by imposing an unnecessary overhead. If you **really** don't need the old data, simply delete it or (if you want to save precious RAM, but keep the old data) move it to a collection which has fewer indices

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg the usual behavior is that only indexes are in ram which are in use. so since we usually query newer data the newer index is in ram. yes when there is a wide range query we have a resource competition but this happens maybe twice a week.

Comment: You are talking of the working set? Right but still I fail to see where Sharding on a single machine will help you. You'd have at least two additional mongod instances requiring RAM and IO without offering any benefit because we would still access the same collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you don't need to shard your content and just need to index your field. Yes you can create index on date field and it would be respected which you can see by visiting the query plan **db.collection.explain("executionStats")**

However, Choosing a shard key is very important. there are few things to consider while choosing the shard key

```
- Write scaling (high cardinality, Randomization)
- Query Isolation. (read)
```

choosing the date field actually gives a very high cardinality however it fails in doing the randomization and as a result all documents are stored into the single shard and hence it limits the write capacity of system. For the same reason ObjectId is discouraged to use as the shard key.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/
Content from the above link..
*"MongoDB generates ObjectId values upon document creation to produce a unique identifier for the object. However, the most significant bits of data in this value represent a time stamp, which means that they increment in a regular and predictable pattern. Even though this value has high cardinality, when using this, any date, or other monotonically increasing number as the shard key, all insert operations will be storing data into a single chunk, and therefore, a single shard. As a result, the write capacity of this shard will define the effective write capacity of the cluster."*

Comment: We have an index on the date field but it is soon not fitting into ram any more. But 90% of the queries are about more recent data and just a few queries go over a wide historic range. sharding should also split the index and since the "historic" node will not be queries very often the node will not hold the index in ram for ever and free up resources for the more recent node (I hope).

Comment: I doubt if in a sharded cluster only a part of index would be loaded in a RAM. Indexes are in RAM always, irrespective of which shard your query is routed to. Why don't u do either of these two things. 1) use horizontal scaling and increase the machines (which i don't think may help in case of timestamp field) 2) think of removing the old and redundant records.

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you might not need sharding, but rather just splitting your large collection to smaller ones, by date. So the live collection only contains recent data, and older data periodically moves to its own archive collection. This would work assuming you don't query the new and old data together.

Comment: This will be plan b but since we have queries over all ranges (just not very often) this is not the preferred way.