# MongoDB shard key as (ObjectId, ObjectId, RandomKey). Unbalanced collections

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to shard a collection with approximately 6M documents. Following are some details about the sharded cluster

1. Mongod version 2.6.7, two shards, 40 % writes, 60% reads.
2. My database has a collection events with around 6M documents. The normal document looks like below:

   {

   ```
         _id         : ObjectId,
         sector_id   : ObjectId,
         subsector_id: ObjectId,
         .
         .
         .

         Many event specific fields go here
         .
         . 
         created_at: Date,
         updated_at: Date,
         uid       : 16DigitRandomKey
   ```

   }
3. Each sector has multiple (1,2, ..100) subsectors and each subsector has multiple events. There are 10000 such sectors, 30000 subsectors and 6M events. The numbers keep growing.
4. The normal read query includes sector_id, subsector_id. Every write operation includes sector_id, subsector_id, uid (randomly generated unique key) and rest of the data.
5. I tried/considered following shard keys and the results are described below:

   a.  _id:hashed --> will not provide query isolation, reason: _id is not passed to read query.

   b.  sector_id :1, subsector_id:1, uid:1 -->  Strange distribution: Few sectors with old ObjectId goes to shard 1, Few sectors having sector_id of mid age(ObjectId) are well balanced and     equally                                               distributed among both shards. Few sectors with recent ObjectId stays on shard 0.

   c. subsector_id: hashed --> results were same as shard key b.

   d. subsector_id:1, uid:1  --> same as b.

   e. subsector_id:hashed, uid:1 --> can not create such index

   f.  uid:1 --> writes are distributed but no query isolation

   What may the reason for this uneven distribution? What can be the right shard key based upon given data.

Answer (score 0):

I see it as an expected behaviour Astro, the sectorIds and subsectorIds are ObjectId type which contains the timestamp as the first 4 bytes which is monotonic in nature and would always go to the same chunk (and hence same shard)  as it failed to provide the randomness which is also pointed by you in point (b).

the best way to choose a shard key is the key which has business meaning (unlike some ObjectId field) and should be mixed with some hash as the suffix to ensure a good random mix on that for equal distribution. if you have a sectorName and subsectorName then pls try out and let us know if its working using that.

you may consider this link to choose the right shard key.

[MongoDB shard by date on a single machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955756/mongodb-shard-by-date-on-a-single-machine/30962793#30962793)

-$

Comment: the only fields considered for the shard key are already shown in sample document. Unfortunately there are no such fields like sectorName and/or subsectorName that can be a part of query or a shard key

Comment: hmmm...sometime its good to reverse the ObjectId field to give it randomness and avoid the problem as i mentioned above. why don't you give a try that.

Comment: sounds good, but that said we have to make change in every get call to pass the sectorid and subsectorid in reverse.